# Python + Django run under a different user on apache2 (httpd), Redhat

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2, redhat

i' ve a django application binded to httpd (apache2) on Red hat, and it works well however i' d like to run it under a different username than apache, so if it writes to the filesystem the file' s owner should be newuser. I' m looking for a solution to achieve this.

I tried to use httpd-itk (after this: http://www.webtatic.com/packages/httpd-itk/), but it complains about:

```
permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=31322): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process
'myapp.djangoserver' on '/var/run/wsgi.31085.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
```

After resolving this (by giving 777 permission for test for the file) i still have apache as the file' s owner.

My conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName myapp
    ServerAlias myapp 
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/myapp

    <Directory /usr/share/myapp>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess syntyma.djangoserver processes=10 threads=20 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup myapp.djangoserver

    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/share/myapp/apache/django.wsgi
    CustomLog logs/myapp-access.log combined
    ErrorLog logs/myapp-error.log

    LogLevel debug
    AssignUserId newuser newuser

</VirtualHost>
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

, and the created testfile:

```
ls -l /tmp/ggg
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 3 Sep  6 09:46 /tmp/ggg
```

.

How could i reach my goal with htttpd-itk or any other solution, like some suEXEC, or similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`WSGIDaemonProcess` has a `user` parameter for the user under which the daemon processes will run. In your case:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess syntyma.djangoserver user=newuser processes=10 etc...
```

From the [documentation](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html):

> user=name | user=#uid.rst
>
> Defines the UNIX user name or numeric user uid of the user that the daemon processes 
>   should be run as. If this option is not supplied
>   the daemon processes will be run as the same user that Apache would
>   run child processes and as defined by the User directive.
>
> Note that this option is ignored if Apache wasn’t started as the root user, in which 
>   case no matter what the settings, the daemon processes will be run as the user that Apache was started as.
>
> Also be aware that mod_wsgi will not allow you to run a daemon process group as the root
>   user due to the security risk of running a
>   web application as root.